# How to use Counter in collections to count words from different lists in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections, count, counter

I have the following code:

```
def myFunc(word):
    for id, sList in enumerate(word):
        counts = Counter(sList)
        print(counts)


myFunc([['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'], ["Banana", "Orange"]])
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({'Apple': 1, 'Orange': 1, 'Banana': 1})
Counter({'Banana': 1, 'Orange': 1})
```

This is great. But what if I want the output dictionary like this:

```
{'Apple': {'Orange':1, 'Banana': 1}, 'Orange': {'Apple':1, 'Banana':2},
  'Banana': {'Apple':1, 'Orange':2}}
```

Which means the keys should be all the different words in my lists. The values are all the words count including only lists where the key appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any function which implements this feature hence I have written a snippet that works at least for the cases I tried, though the solution is not very elegant. It includes clumsily nested for loops and if statements. I believe a better solution can be found.

The problem can be divided in two parts: Getting the unique keys and corresponding values. Getting the keys is easy for which I used `Counter()` itself, though `set()` can also be used. To get the corresponding values is tricky part. For this I took each unique key and iterated over the dictionaries to find to which dictionaries the key belongs. When a dictionary is found, take the other keys in the dictionary and iterate over all the dictionaries in which key is present to sum up the counters.

```
from collections import Counter
# countered_list contains Counter() of individual lists.
countered_list = []
# Gives the unique keys.
complete = []
def myFunc(word):
    for each_list in word:
        complete.extend(each_list)
        countered_list.append(Counter(each_list))

    # set() can also be used instead of Counter()
    counts = Counter(complete)
    output = {key:{} for key in counts}

    # Start iteration with each key in count => key is unique
    for key in counts:
        # Iterate over the dictionaries in countered_list
        for each_dict in countered_list:
            # if key is in each_dict then iterate over all the other keys in dict
            if key in each_dict:
                for other_keys in each_dict:
                    # Excludes the key
                    if key != other_keys:
                        temp = 0
                        # Now iterate over all dicts for other_keys and add the value to temp
                        for every_dict in countered_list:
                            # Excludes the dictionaries in which key is not present.
                            if key in every_dict:
                                temp += every_dict[other_keys]
                        output[key][other_keys] = temp

    print(output)
```

Here are some test cases:

```
>>> new_list = [['a','a'],['b','b'],['c','c']]
>>> myFunc(new_list)
{'a': {}, 'c': {}, 'b': {}}
>>> new_list = [['a','a'],['b','b'],['c','c','a','a']]
>>> myFunc(new_list)
{'a': {'c': 2}, 'c': {'a': 2}, 'b': {}}
>>> new_list = [['a','a'],['b','b','a'],['c','c','a','a']]
>>> myFunc(new_list)
{'a': {'c': 2, 'b': 2}, 'c': {'a': 2}, 'b': {'a': 1}}
>>> new_list = [['ab','ba'],['ba','ab','ab'],['c','c','ab','ba']]
>>> myFunc(new_list)
{'c': {'ab': 1, 'ba': 1}, 'ab': {'c': 2, 'ba': 3}, 'ba': {'c': 2, 'ab': 4}}
```